# Biblatex - First edition in square brackets and number of edition as superscript

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biblatex-chicago

For a research I have to use a precise bibliographic style, which forces me to write after the last and current year of publication of the book the **first** year of publication in square brackets and the number of editions as superscript. So, as an example,

> A. Gomme, An Historical Commentary on Thucydides, London: OUP Oxford,
> 1972 [1956<sup>4</sup>]

That means that the last edition of the book is from 1972, the first edition has been published in 1956 and, since then, 4 more editions have been published.
My original idea was to simply write in the `.bib` file `year={{1972 [1956^4]}}`. The problem is, that when i cite the book I want that just the current year is printed (so, in this example, the result should just be `Gomme 1972`, and **NOT** `Gomme 1972 [1956⁴]`

So that does not work. Any ideas?

MWEB:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
    bibstyle=authortitle,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{Gomme1956,
  title={An Historical Commentary on Thucydides},
  author={Gomme, A.},
  year={1972},
  publisher={OUP Oxford},
  address={London},
  edition={2},
  origdate={1956}
}
\end{filecontents}
  
\begin{document}

\cite{Gomme1956}

\printbibliography
         
\end{document}
```

EDIT: As Seamus suggests, I should work with `origdate` and `edition` fields. However, I don't know how to stylize them in the proper way, so that the result is `1972 [1956⁴]`.

Comment: biblatex defines `origdate` and bibtex has an `edition` field. So I would recommend using them, and then defining the citation style using those elements.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there is no style/package that formats them as I wish, and I don't know how to stylizing them.

Comment: Semantically, `origdate` and `edition` are definitely the correct fields here. But it is very possible that `biblatex-chicago` does not immediately produce the output you hope for. The thing with `biblatex-chicago` is that it is a specialised style that tries to implement CMoS recommendations as closely as possible in LaTeX. That means it has to use some very complex code and is sometimes a pain to modify. (I suspect this is the case here, as the date code in `biblatex-chicago` is quite complex.)

Comment: However, I am using the `biblatex` package with `style=chicago-authordate`, and not the `biblatex-chicago` package

Comment: A MWEB (minimal working example with Bibliography)  would be helpful: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/231952. I have tried with `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` but `\textcite` does not print the `date` field. Another thing: you have shown an authortitle-style entry while the citation (Gomme 1972) is in authoryear format. Is that what you want? Are you mixing two different styles?

Comment: @Ivan I added the MWEB

Comment: Even if you use `style=chicago-authordate` you are using `biblatex-chicago`, because `chicago-authordate,` is part of the `biblatex-chicago` bundle. Unlike other `biblatex` styles, `biblatex-chicago` should normally be loaded with `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` and not with `\usepackage{biblatex}`. But in your MWE you immediately overwrite the selection of the `biblatex-chicago` style `style=chicago-authordate,` with `citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle,`, which means you are not using `style=chicago-authordate` at all and are not using `biblatex-chicago` either. ...

Comment: ... I strongly suggest you remove `style=chicago-authordate,` to avoid confusing others (and possibly yourself) in the future.

Comment: @moewe Gotcha. Done.

Comment: @Urel see `cmsdate` on page `164` from biblatex-chicago manual. "`cmsdate=off is the default: (Smith 1985).`, `cmsdate=both prints both the origdate and the date, using the Manual’s standard format: (Author [1926] 1985) in parenthetical citations, Author (1926) 1985 outside parentheses, e.g., in the reference list.`, "

Comment: @Mafsi that is very useful, although I hadn't intention to use `biblatex-chicago`! Now do you know how can I place the origdate after the date, and print the edition number as superscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MWE to start with. I have defined the new field `totaleditions` which is mapped to `usera` to be used inside the new macro `totaleditions`. This macro is used at the end of the `publisher+location+date macro` if the `origdate` field is not empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@book{Gomme1956,
  title={An Historical Commentary on Thucydides},
  author={Gomme, A.},
  date={1972},
  publisher={OUP Oxford},
  location={London},
  totaleditions={4},
  origdate={1956}
}
\end{filecontents}
   
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
   \map{
     \step[fieldsource=totaleditions, fieldtarget=usera]
    }  
  }
}

\newbibmacro*{totaleditions}{%
\iffieldundef{origyear}{}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{\printfield{origyear}%
  \textsuperscript{\printfield{usera}}}
 }
}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{totaleditions}%
  \newunit}
  
\begin{document}

\cite{Gomme1956}

\printbibliography
         
\end{document}
```

[image]